# CKEditor and Jasmine test in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, ckeditor, karma-runner

I'm writing tests for a component which uses CKEditor. When launch the test I get Error:

[image]

Test :

```
describe('document.edit component test', () => {

        beforeEach(() => {

          TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormsModule],

            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
            declarations: [DocumentEditComponent],
            providers: [{provide: AppConfig, useValue: appConfig},
             {provide: DocumentsService, useValue: documentsService},
             {provide: NgbModal, useValue: modalService},
             {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoute},
             {provide: BaThemeSpinner, useValue: loader},
             {provide: PopupResultService, useValue: popupResultService},
            ],
          })

          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DocumentEditComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;
        })

        tests();
      })
```

In component it looks like:

declare let CKEDITOR: any;

```
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef, OnInit, OnDestroy } 
from '@angular/core';
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Can you check in your network in your ckeditor file is served correctly from your test framework or if it is a 404? With karma you would have to include it into the `files:[]` option in the karma.conf.js. Otherwise, you can use `ng2-ckeditor` to import as angular dependency.

Comment: Added path of ckeditor.js in karma.conf.js to files:[] and it all worked! Thank you!

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to include the text of the error message instead of an image of the text? Images of text are not searchable, nor are they accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I will post my comment here since it seems to have solved your problem.

Karma will not serve static files when running angular tests. The files referenced in your application have to be added to the [files](http://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/config/files.html) option in the `karma.conf.js`. You could also look into `webpack` config to import and alias it through the `ProvidePlugin`.

Have a look at the plugins made for angular which most of the time will not require you to add standalone scripts tags and can be bundled with webpack in your `vendor` file. You can